# Find the function which satisfies the given conditions

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f :R \to R$  is a function satisfying $f(10-x) = f(x)$ and $f(2-x) = f(2+x)$

for all $x$ belonging to $R$.If $f(0) = 101$, then find the minimum possible no.

of values of $x$ satisfying $f(x) = 101$ for $x$ belonging to $[0,30]$.

As $f(2-x) = f(2+x)$, hence $f(x)$ is symmetric about the line $x=2$ but I am not able to understand how to use other information. Could someone give me slight hint?

Answer (score 1):

Hint (as requested): What can you say about  $f(5)$, using the first condition?

What about $f(4)$? What's the second condition tell you about $f(0)$? What's the first condition tell you about $f(10)$? Do you notice a pattern here?

Your question title is a bad one, because you cannot find "the function" satisfying these conditions -- there may be many many such functions.

Comment: I got $f(0)=f(4)=f(6)=f(10)=101$. But not able to comment on $f(5)$

Comment: What can you say about the shape of the graph near $x = 5$. And did you notice a pattern in the questions I asked and the answers you got?

Comment: @JohnHughes Is there any pattern? It looks to me  that 4 is the answer. What am I missing?

Comment: SPOILER: The first rule tells you that $x$ and $10-x$ must get assigned the same value. The second tells you that $x$ and $4-x$ must get assigned the same value. [To see this, let $t = x + 2$; then $x-2 = t-4$, so $f(4-t) = f(t)$.] Combinte these two to show that $f(u) = f(6 + u)$ for any $u$. Then apply the second again to conclude that $f(u) = f(u-2)$. Hence $f$ takes the same value on all even numbers.

Comment: SPOILER, continued: Since $x$ and $10-x$ are either both even or both odd (for integer $x$), and similarly for $x$ and $4-x$, knowing $f(0)$ and these two facts can only tell you about the value of $f$ on other even numbers. Since it in fact determines the value of $f$ on all even numbers, you're done: you can confidently say that $f$ takes the value $101$ for at least 21 values in that interval. By defining $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$ except even integers, you can show that $21$ is the best possible claim.

Answer (score -2):

By condition $f(2-x)=f(2+x)$ we can say $f$ is periodic with period $4$ and with condition $f(10-x)=f(x)$ means $f$ is periodic with period $10$ so as $f$ is the function satisfying both the properties so its period should divide $4$ and $10$ so period of $f$ will be either $1$, $2$ or any number. But as we want the minimum so period should be the maximum of all these so the period should be $2$ which implies it has $16$ values of in $[0,30]$ satisfying given conditions.